# Docker Node JS - docker-compose.yml

Tags: javascript, nodejs, docker

Hola intento montar un simpler servidoren docker con una imagen de `Node JS` pero no corre para nada

He buscado en todos lados pero solo encuentro que ejecutan casi siempre `bin/www` ¿es nescesario crearlo?, no puedo correrlo con

`npm run local:dev`

**scripts**

```
  "scripts": {
    "local": "cross-env NODE_ENV=local babel-node src/index.js",
    "local:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=dev nodemon src/index.js --exec babel-node"
  }
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /home/app
USER node
ENV PORT 3000

EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash
```

**docker-compose**

```
version: "3"
services:
  nod_dev_env:
    build: .
    container_name: node-docker
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/app
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Hola que tal Revisa este ejemplo espero te pueda servir

[Github Docker/Nodejs](https://github.com/dockerfile/nodejs)

```
FROM dockerfile/python

# Install Node.js
RUN \
  cd /tmp && \
  wget http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz && \
  tar xvzf node-latest.tar.gz && \
  rm -f node-latest.tar.gz && \
  cd node-v* && \
  ./configure && \
  CXX="g++ -Wno-unused-local-typedefs" make && \
  CXX="g++ -Wno-unused-local-typedefs" make install && \
  cd /tmp && \
  rm -rf /tmp/node-v* && \
  npm install -g npm && \
  printf '\n# Node.js\nexport PATH="node_modules/.bin:$PATH"' >> /root/.bashrc

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /data

# Define default command.
CMD ["bash"]
```

este seria un ejemplo del dockerfile saludos

Answer (score 0):

Viendo la forma de tus lineas dockerfile las veo similar a un curso de docker que aprendi hace poco.
Yo solucione (ubicandome en la direccionn/carpeta del proyecto) ejecutando en la barra de comandos "npm install", proba si te funciona.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM node:12-alpine as build-deps

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install --production --no-progress

COPY . ./

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine

COPY --from=build-deps /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf 
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx","-g","daemon off;"]
```

Comment: Las respuestas que son solo código son consideradas de baja calidad, por favor agrega la explicación correspondiente de lo que tu código hace. ;)